# Shrink UITextView for 3.5 inch iPhone Display

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I have a view controller that looks like this: [image]

This is the layout for a 4 inch iPhone display. I'd like to add support for 3.5 inch screens so that the large UITextView shrinks, allowing the Notify and Done button to still exist at the bottom, and maintain the size of everything else. I'm totally lost how to do this and I can't find any clear tutorials. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is pin the label Event Name to the top and pin it's width and height and center in container. Then pin the text box location duration to the Event Name label and pin width and height and center in container. Then go to the bottom and pin the two icons notify and done to the bottom, pin height and width of both, then pin the notify icon to the left and the done icon to the right.  Finally you can now work with your big text box in the middle. You now just need to pin the top of the text box to the location duration text, pin the bottom to the top of the done icon, and pin both sides to the super view.   This will allow your big text box to resize for both 4 and 3.5 inch displays.